# is there a usage called "Full Professor"?

Tags: etiquette

I would like to know if the usage of "Full Professor" is valid or not as my language ability does not let me decide on this particular thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The highest level of professorship is "Professor". The title "Full Professor" is often used to distinguish from other lower rank positions (Assistant Professor, Associate Professor, etc).

(Edit after Henry's comment)

Comment: At least at many institutions, "Professor" is not a shortening, but the actual formal name of that rank. "Full Professor" is usually an informal term used to distinguish the actual rank from lower ranks which are sometimes informally called professors as well (and where "Professor" may appear in the title, like "Associate Professor").

Comment: It would be good to clarify for the OP that you generally wouldn't refer to someone as "Full Professor Smith", only "Professor Smith" - such as in person, in an email, etc.. Professor Smith may hold the position of "assistant professor", "associate professor", or "full professor" as a job title, but in all cases their honorific professional title is just "Professor".